# Convert nested dictionary to a json with a principal key in each line

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary which I am trying to convert to a JSON file using json.dumps(). Using the following code:

```
import json

dictionary={'Galicia':{'ACoruña':1,'Pontevedra':2,'Lugo':3,'Ourense':4},'Asturias':{'Oviedo':5},
            'Castilla':{'Leon':6,'Burgos':7,'Avila':8}}
print(dictionary)

with open ('prueba.txt','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(dictionary,outfile,ensure_ascii=False,indent=4)
```

I get this:

```
{
    "Galicia": {
        "ACoruña": 1,
        "Pontevedra": 2,
        "Lugo": 3,
        "Ourense": 4
    },
    "Asturias": {
        "Oviedo": 5
    },
    "Castilla": {
        "Leon": 6,
        "Burgos": 7,
        "Avila": 8
    }
}
```

But I would like to put in my JSON in a way that each principal key is on a new line to make it easier to read. I would like it to look like this :

```
{
"Galicia": { "ACoruña": 1 , "Pontevedra": 2, "Lugo": 3, "Ourense": 4},
"Asturias": { "Oviedo": 5},
"Castilla": { "Leon": 6, "Burgos": 7, "Avila": 8}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might find that hard to achieve. Since JASON is used so much with JS, a lot of the formatters adopt K&R style output.

You could read up and see if there is a way to override the formatter with your own custom one, but that will likely be a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
    dictionary = {'Galicia': {'ACoruña': 1, 'Pontevedra': 2, 'Lugo': 3, 'Ourense': 4}, 'Asturias': {'Oviedo': 5},
                  'Castilla': {'Leon': 6, 'Burgos': 7, 'Avila': 8}}
    print(dictionary)

    with open('prueba.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write('{\n')
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            outfile.write('{0}, {1}\n'.format(key, value))
        outfile.write('}')
```